# What is the best PCL feature descriptor for aligning of occupancy map and point cloud?

Tags: pcl, laser-scan-matcher, perception-pcl

I am working on a delocalisation monitor for amcl. I am planning to use NDT for local refinement. However I have trouble selecting proper point feature descriptor for map point clouds. can anyone suggest any white paper or feature descriptor to use for this problem ?